# simulation algorithm implementation in C/C++

Tags: c, implementation

Let a row of 8000 lamps. Initially, only the one located to the left is lit.
Then, every second, the following operation is performed: each lamp changes state (on or off) if the one on its left was lit a second before. The leftmost lamp stays on all the time. This operation is instantaneous.
The process stops when the lamp at the right end lights for the first time.
How many lights are on?

My following implementation of the problem is false, can you help me?

```
#include <cstdio>

int t[8001][2];

int main()
{
    t[1][0] = 1;
    t[1][1] = 1;
    int cpt1 = 0, ip = 0;
    while (t[8000][0] != 1 && t[8000][1] != 1)
    {
        ip++; 
        for (int j=2;j<8001;j++)
        {
            if(t[j-1][!(ip&1)])
                t[j][(ip & 1)] = !t[j][!(ip & 1)];      
        }
    }   

    for(int j = 1;j < 8001; j++)
        cpt1 += t[j][1];

    printf("cpt=%d\n", cpt1);
}
```

Comment: First thought - isn't that 8001 lamps? In any case - "is false" doesn't tell us much about why it's wrong. Include an error message, or a reason that it's wrong. Edit: nvm, you're using 1-indexing.....

Comment: it's not 8001 and not 4001 as my code finds I don't have the solution but I know it's wrong.

Comment: It may help if you define a structure for the lamp with a bool `isSwitchedOn` field. That way, it may be easier to spot the error. Your code in current state is very hard to understand.

Comment: Why does it need 2D array? This program is hardly readable. *Update* Ah, OK. I guess it is for "double-buffering". Still not readable though

Comment: I may have used a boolean but there is the need of 2D structure to implement the changes state (on or off) of the lamps.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: To keep current and next states separate.

Comment: Anyway. start with small number and print out the output for every cycle to debug it. If I understand correctly, the leftmost lamp should "launch" on light every two cycles, which will  propagate right every cycle.

Comment: `#include<cstdio>` + `[C]` tag - hmmm.

Comment: It is 4001 for me.  Unclear what "My following implementation of the problem is false" implies -  please add detail.

Comment: My implementation gives 4001, but I know the solution of the problem is not that.

Comment: @chux how can it be 4001? Isn't it "propagated" by 1 each second?

Comment: @asterix "but I know the solution of the problem is not that. "  --> What do you expect?

Comment: @chux Oh, sorry. Misread the question itself.

Comment: C is not the same as C++ (in which you'll better use [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)). So choose a language and edit your question

Comment: BTW fix-my-code  questions are **off-topic**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is missing an update when the left does not change.

Code simplified (zero based offset, use of `bool`) and corrected below

```
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 8000

bool t[N][2];

int main(void) {
  t[0][0] = true;
  t[0][1] = true;
  int ip = 0;

  while (t[N - 1][0] == 0 && t[N - 1][1] == 0) {
    ip = !ip;
    for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) {
      if (t[j - 1][!ip]) {
        t[j][ip] = !t[j][!ip];
      } else {
        t[j][ip] = t[j][!ip];  // add
      }
    }
  }

  int cpt1 = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    cpt1 += t[j][1];
  }
  printf("N=%d cpt=%d\n", N, cpt1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
N=8000 cpt=2048
```

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses C header files rather than C++ header files
3. performs the desired operation, but not the fastest possible algorithm
4. is liberally commented

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int t1[8000];   // initially all zeros
int t2[8000];


int main( void )
{
    // setup initial conditions
    int numLitLights = 0;
    t1[0] = 1;


    // while stop condition not true
    while ( t1[7999] != 1 )
    {
        // make one pass through lamps
        // update values
        for (int j=0; j<7999; j++)
        {
            if( t1[j] )
            {
                t2[j+1] = ( t1[j+1] )? 0 : 1;
            }
        }

        // update original
        for( int j=0; j< 8000; j++ )
        {
            t1[j] = t2[j];
        }
    }

    // count lit lamps
    for(int j = 0; j < 8000; j++)
    {
       if( t1[j] )
       {
           numLitLights++;
       }
    }

    // output number of lit lamps
    printf( "number of lit lamps: %d\n", numLitLights );
} // end function: main
```

The result (number of lamps lit) is

```
1024
```

Comment: your implementation and your result 1024 are false, see the solution by chux

Comment: @asterix.  You may be right.  Do show me the source of the error.  Is it a logic error or is it my misunderstanding of the parameters of the problem?

Comment: you missed to initialize t2[0]=1; with this you have  the right idem solution of 2048.

Comment: @asterix,  Thanks,  It is always the little things that get me.  Note: I originally wrote the code with both of the t1[0] and t2[0] initialized to 1  Then I made the mistake of thinking that I did not need to initialize the t2[0] *sigh*